# How do I find if a word is found in a string in Liquid for Shopify?

Tags: json, twig, shopify, liquid

Per the documentation for Liquid (https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/) I can use the keyword **contains** to find out if a word is present in a String. However, when I do the following code, it breaks my code:

```
{% if item.metadata['shopify_tags'] contains "outlet" %}
    <br>All items are final sale, non-refundable, and not eligible for exchange.
{% endif %}
```

When using Postman, the JSON returned is:

```
"metadata": {
                        
                        "shopify_product_type": "Pajama Set",
                        "shopify_tags": "_tab_outlet, _tab_pajama-set-sizing, birthday, bride, cities, city, city toile, customshop, fashion, monogramshop, mother, Nashville, Nashville Toile, new, outlet, pajama sets, pj, pjs, retail, Toile, Toile Shop, womens",
                        "barcode": "901868449",
                        "shopify_current_inventory": "66",
                        "current_stock": "66",
                    "ShopifyVariantID": "32662090186849"
```

It seems that as soon as I use the word "contains", it breaks my code. How would I search if "outlet" is found in the product tags?

EDIT: Apparently I'm working in Twig instead of just Liquid. This works:

```
{% if "outlet" in item.metadata['shopfy_tags'] %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be working with the JSON code when you have access to the backend liquid. There is nothing called `item.metadata['shopify_tags]'` in shopify It should be `product.tags` if you are in the product page.
[Shopify Cheat Sheet](https://www.shopify.com/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet)

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
 {% if tag == "_tab_outlet" %}  
  do something
 {% elsif tag contains "outlet" %}
  do something
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```